# Examples of CW-complex with finite homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

$CP^\infty$ can be viewed as a CW-complex with a cell in every even dimensions. The only non-zero homotopy group is $\pi_2(CP^\infty)=Z$ which is infinite. I like to know examples (the more the better) of CW-complexes with finite homotopy groups.

For example, I like to know the number of cells in each dimensions, and the chain complex formed by those cells, so that one can compute cohomology. (I like to know the chain complex, in addition to the cohomology).

Comment: Replace C by R, for example. Also look at Eilenberg Maclane spaces.

Comment: Thanks. What are the CW-complex of Eilenberg Maclane spaces? Here I like to know the CW-complex itself. I like to know examples beyond $BG$.

Comment: For Eilenberg Mac-Lane spaces, look at Arkowitz's Book "An Introduction to Homotopy Theory", chapter 2.5. He gives a CW construction of EM spaces. You can then build any a space with any finite number of homotopy groups in any dimensions by taking suitable products of EM spaces. I believe that $S^1$ is the only finite CW complex with a finite number of non-trivial homotopy groups, and this is essentially due to the Serre's theorem that $S^n$ has non-trivial homotopy groups in arbitrarily high dimensions for $n>1$.

Comment: By "finite homotopy groups", I mean each homotopy group is finite.

Comment: The paper by G.. Ellis Topology   Vol.  36, No.  2,  pp.  501-504,    1997 , "spaces with finitely many nontrivial  homotopy groups all of which are finite"  sounds relevant.